# How to open two emulators in Android Studio _in two different windows_?

Tags: android-studio

I know how to run two different emulators but I can't have them in foreground at the same time. If I choose one, the other is hidden as window tab.
It would be useful for ping-pong communication app testing. I don't find the way.